# How to sum the amounts in a xslt for same ids appearing in XML

Tags: xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I need to produce a text file in the output. I have to first check if a perosn has aby of the following node  PreTaxAmt,MatchAmt,RothAmt, then produce a single line in output with required values and then I have to check if the perosn has LoanAmt node, if they have then I have to create another entry for that person. I was able to code till this point but now I am having a requiremnet where if the same person is repated more than once for example below laurel Alex , I need to produce just one entry for single participant id and the PreTaxAmt,MatchAmt,RothAmt amount should be summed up in the first entry in the output and in the in the loan entry row the LoanAmt should be summed up.

Here is my xml.

```
<Report_Data >
<Report_Entry>
    <Participant_ID>03300</Participant_ID>
    <Workers>
        <FULL_PART_Time_Indicator>1</FULL_PART_Time_Indicator>
        <Last_Name>Mary</Last_Name>
        <First_Name>Mehul</First_Name>

    </Workers>
    <End_Date_from_Pay_Period>2016-01-03-08:00</End_Date_from_Pay_Period>
    <PreTaxAmt>100.8</PreTaxAmt>
    <MatchAmt>100.8</MatchAmt>
    <RothAmt>0</RothAmt>
    <LoanAmt>0</LoanAmt>
</Report_Entry>
<Report_Entry>
    <Participant_ID>10600</Participant_ID>
    <Workers>
        <FULL_PART_Time_Indicator>1</FULL_PART_Time_Indicator>
        <Last_Name>Laurel</Last_Name>
        <First_Name>Alex</First_Name>      
    </Workers>
    <End_Date_from_Pay_Period>2016-01-03-08:00</End_Date_from_Pay_Period>
    <PreTaxAmt>61.48</PreTaxAmt>
    <MatchAmt>61.47</MatchAmt>
    <RothAmt>0</RothAmt>
    <LoanAmt>0</LoanAmt>      
</Report_Entry>
<Report_Entry>
    <Participant_ID>10600</Participant_ID>
    <Workers>
        <FULL_PART_Time_Indicator>1</FULL_PART_Time_Indicator>
        <Last_Name>Laurel</Last_Name>
        <First_Name>Alex</First_Name>
        <Middle_Name>S</Middle_Name>  
    </Workers>
    <End_Date_from_Pay_Period>2016-01-03-08:00</End_Date_from_Pay_Period>
    <PreTaxAmt>0</PreTaxAmt>
    <MatchAmt>0</MatchAmt>
    <RothAmt>0</RothAmt>
    <LoanAmt>0</LoanAmt>  
</Report_Entry>
<Report_Entry>
    <Participant_ID>13100</Participant_ID>
    <Workers>
        <FULL_PART_Time_Indicator>1</FULL_PART_Time_Indicator>
        <Last_Name>Smita</Last_Name>
        <First_Name>Paul</First_Name>       
    </Workers>
    <End_Date_from_Pay_Period>2016-01-03-08:00</End_Date_from_Pay_Period>
    <PreTaxAmt>0</PreTaxAmt>
    <MatchAmt>0</MatchAmt>
    <RothAmt>0</RothAmt>
    <LoanAmt>0</LoanAmt>
</Report_Entry>
```

Here is my xslt :

```
 <xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:for-each select="Report_Data/Report_Entry">
    <xsl:if test="(PreTaxAmt) or(MatchAmt) or (RothAmt) ">
         <xsl:call-template name="DataRecords"/>
    </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:for-each select="Report_Data/Report_Entry">
    <xsl:if test="LoanAmt">
        <xsl:call-template name="LoanDataRecord"/>
    </xsl:if>

    </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="DataRecords">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="." group-by="wd:Participant_ID">
    <xsl:variable name="ParticpantLoan" select="current-grouping-key()"/> 

!-- Transaction Code -->
<xsl:value-of select="'Contribution'"/>

<!-- Participant Number -->
<xsl:value-of select="Participant_ID,$filler),1,9"/>

<!-- FT/PT Indicator -->
<xsl:value-of select="substring(concat(Workers/FULL_PART_Time_Indicator,$filler),1,1)"/>  

<!-- Contribution Amount1 -->  
<xsl:value-of select="(sum(current-group()/PreTaxAmt))"/>

<!-- Contribution Amount2 -->
<xsl:value-of select="(sum(current-group()/MatchAmt))"/>

<!-- Contribution Amount3 -->
<xsl:value-of select="(sum(current-group()/RothAmt))"/>
<xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/> 

</xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>     


<xsl:template name="LoanDataRecord">

    <xsl:for-each-group select="." group-by="Participant_ID">
    <xsl:variable name="ParticpantLoan" select="current-grouping-key()"/> 

<!-- Transaction Code -->
<xsl:value-of select="substring(concat('LoanData',$filler),1,3)"/>


<!-- Participant Number -->
<xsl:value-of select="substring(concat(Participant_ID,$filler),1,9)"/>


<!-- Loan Amt -->
<xsl:value-of select="(sum(current-group()/LoanAmt))"/>


<xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/> 

</xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

The output should have six lines.
Also, how can I calculate the total count of the records in my output file. Earlier I was using below code but now since  there would be duplicate SSN how should I modify my existing code for counting ..
 0 ]  or Report_Data/Report_Entry/MatchAmt[number(.) > 0 ] or Report_Data/Report_Entry/RothAmt[number(.) > 0 ])+

```
 count(Report_Data/Report_Entry/LoanAmt[number(.) > 0 ])
```

Comment: If you need to group and sum then in XSLT 2.0 you can use e.g. `<xsl:for-each-group select="//Report_Entry" group-by="string-join(Workers/*[ends-with(local-name(), 'Name')], '|')"><xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/PreTaxAmt)"/>...</xsl:for-each-group>`.

Comment: Sorry I had not placed my complete code so I have just now edited and saved. I did use the group by and sum but still not getting the putput. Also how can I count the total number of record in the output . I have placed the code that I had above. what tweaking do I need to do to make sure that the same SSN are not counted twice in the total number of records.

Comment: Ok, so I got my output with grouping now. Can you please shed some light on what tweaking to I need to do on my count code ( to get the total number of records in the output file ) so that the I can count the nodes with duplicate SSN only once.

Comment: Could you post the exact output you expect to get as the result of transforming the input example? -- Also, your XSLT is missing some variable definitions and has a lot of syntax errors - please fix that.

Comment: I got the xslt working after using the group by and if.